# java.lang.Exception: No signature of method: static java.util.Base64$Encoder.encodeToString() is applicable for argument types: ([B)

Tags: java, groovy

I got this piece of code in `Groovy`:

```
def getPhoto(params){
    def data = entity.find(params).first();
    byte[] mybyte = (byte[]) data.photo;
    String str = java.util.Base64.Encoder.encodeToString(mybyte);
    return str;
}
```

But when this code is executed it throws an **error** saying:

```
java.lang.Exception: No signature of method: static java.util.Base64$Encoder.encodeToString() is applicable for argument types: ([B) values: {[-1, -40, -1, -32, 0, 16, 74, 70, 73, 70, 0,...too long...
```

**UPDATED**

```
org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.MethodSelectionException: Could not find which method <init>() to invoke from this list:
  private java.util.Base64$Encoder#<init>(boolean, [B, int, boolean)
   java.util.Base64$Encoder#<init>(boolean, [B, int, boolean, java.util.Base64$1)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:2419)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1250)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeConstructor(MetaClassImpl.java:1182)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeConstructorOf(InvokerHelper.java:805)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeNewN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:227)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeNew0(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:234)
        at JobSearchService.getPhoto(script1000034.groovy:113)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:226)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:333)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodOnCurrentN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:77)
        at JobSearchService$_search_closure2.doCall(script1000034.groovy:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:226)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:248)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:754)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:292)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:305)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1078)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1055)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ReflectionMetaMethod.invoke(ReflectionMetaMethod.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.NewInstanceMetaMethod.invoke(NewInstanceMetaMethod.java:54)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:226)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:754)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:765)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:753)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:167)
        at JobSearchService.search(script1000034.groovy:57)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:226)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:754)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:86)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:226)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:754)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokePojoMethod(InvokerHelper.java:765)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(InvokerHelper.java:753)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.invokeMethodN(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:167)
        at JobSearchService.invokeMethod(script1000034.groovy)
        at com.rameses.osiris3.script.ScriptExecutor.invokeMethod(ScriptExecutor.java:41)
        at com.rameses.osiris3.script.ManagedScriptExecutor$1.call(ManagedScriptExecutor.java:142)
        at com.rameses.osiris3.script.InterceptorChain.fireChain(InterceptorChain.java:79)
        at com.rameses.osiris3.script.ManagedScriptExecutor.execute(ManagedScriptExecutor.java:140)
        at com.rameses.osiris3.script.ScriptRunnable.run(ScriptRunnable.java:62)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
error class java.lang.Exception Could not find which method <init>() to invoke from this list:
  private java.util.Base64$Encoder#<init>(boolean, [B, int, boolean)
   java.util.Base64$Encoder#<init>(boolean, [B, int, boolean, java.util.Base64$1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Im using JDK 6, this is the best approach:

```
new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(mybyte);
```

Comment: Don't you think that information could go in the question next time?

Comment: Yes! I guess so.   :)

Answer (score 2):

`Encoder#encodeToString(byte[])` is an instance method, not a static method. Call it on an instance:

```
new Base64.Encoder().encodeToString(mybyte)
```

Note that [`Encoder` is thread-safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html), so you can save a copy in a private static final field.

Using `@TypeChecked` or `@CompileStatic` on your method will prevent many errors like this.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to run your code, but its giving me an error, please see the updated question.

Comment: This class did'nt exist in JDK 6.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.encodeBase64(mybyte)
```